# java - I don't understand method syntax

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the class:

```
public abstract class Entry{
    protected static <T extends Entry> List<T> all(Class<T> cls) {
        blah blah
    }
```

And the child of it:

```
class Article extends Entry {
    public static List<Article> all() throws SQLException {
        return Entry.all(Article.class);
    }
}
```

I don't understand the syntax of the method:

```
protected static <T extends Entry> List<T> all(Class<T> cls)
```

Why can we not just do it like this?:

```
protected static List<T> all(Class<T> cls)
```

Comment: "Why we just can not do like this?:" and how compiler should know what `T` in `List<T>` is? Should it assume that it is some like `String` or generic type?

Comment: But it is called polymorphism - no? Let substitute with String: protected static List<String> all(Class<String> cls). Is it invalid??? Yes compiler gives error. But my question is why? I want to understendthe syntax.

Comment: Because `T` must be declared. *Everything* referred to must have a declaration. ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected static <T extends Entry> List<T> all(Class<T> cls)
```

This means that the method named `all` has a [type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) `T` which must be a subtype of `Entry` (or `Entry` itself).

[Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials explains the syntax and what this means.

> Why we just can not do like this?:
>
> ```
> protected static List<T> all(Class<T> cls)
> ```

Because the compiler doesn't automatically know that with `T` you mean a type parameter instead of a concrete type.

Note that for type parameters, a single upper-case letter is most often used for the name of the type parameter. But this is only a convention. You could use any name that is a valid identifier.

If a name is supposed to be a type parameter, it has to be declared as such, otherwise the Java compiler assumes it's a concrete type.